# Relationship between RMS-current and energy stored in a solenoid

Tags: constant-current, solenoid, energy

Regarding the formula for energy stored in the magnetic field of a solenoid (U=1/2LI^2), I presume that the RMS value for an alternating current could be used for the I-value. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

> *I presume that the RMS value for an alternating current could be used for the I-value. Is this correct?*

No, that wouldn't be correct. We use the peak current for the maximum energy stored. Imagine if your current was 7.071 amps RMS; the peak would be 10 amps and, the peak energy stored in a 1 henry inductor would be 50 joules.

If we used the 7.071 amp figure, the energy calculated would be 25 joules and, it isn't a very meaningful quantity for all applications I can think of. You can make an argument that it represents the average energy value stored but, still, I've never come across a reason to use this figure.

Comment: There is a sense in which it's meaningful, stored energy and reactive power being proportional (AC sinusoidal steady-state conditions); but then one needs a \$2 \pi F\$ in there too.